# VSTO Ribbon and XLA Addin

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, vba

I have created a ribbon control using VSTO, and want to call function in xla on click of button, would like to know
1> how can I call xla function from ribbon created in VSTO
2> How can I install xla plugin along with ribbon installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I did it

```
        var macroFilePath = Path.Combine(addinPath, addinName);
        var addins = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns.Add(macroFilePath);

        if (!addins.Installed)
        {
            addins.Installed = true;                  
        }
        var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

        string macroToInvoke = string.Format("{0}!{1}", LibraryName, FunctionName);
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run(macroToInvoke);
```